# add new value to a dropdownlist

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I have a dropdown list with the following values:

> 0,10,20,30.

Now i want to replace the 0 with "off".
The logic which i used for showing the values are

```
List<int> refreshList = GetAutoRefreshTimeIntervals();
this.dataSetVM.RefreshIntervalList = new SelectList(refreshList);

// The default value in the drop down should be 30 which should be config driven.
// If the configuration has any invalid value other than the valid entries in the Dropdown, the default value of 30 should be used.
if (refreshList.Contains(refreshInterval))
{
     this.dataSetVM.RefreshInterval = refreshInterval;
}
else
{
     this.dataSetVM.RefreshInterval = 30; // default will be set as 30
}
```

Comment: You should change List type as string. Then change 0 with off.

Comment: You had tagged `model-view-controller` but have not displayed either the model, nor the controller.

Comment: but the value of the drop down should be 0

Comment: Change `GetAutoRefreshTimeIntervals()` to return `List<string>` & also set `refreshList` as `List<string>`. Also you should consider parsing submitted value from `RefreshIntervalList` to integer in POST method.

Comment: Could you please provide me an example.